# Where to put the code for a dynamically updated user flair to be used by the community?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I created a web page template for a dynamically updated [user flair](https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1937747.png) that doesn't use a blurry image but plain HTML elements and JavaScript. Now I'm wondering where the best place is to put its code to be used by the community?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best place would be [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/)

From its on-topic page:

> If your question is about …
>
> - the Stack Exchange API
> - applications built on the Stack Exchange API
> - scripts or browser extensions that work with Stack Exchange sites … it is welcome here.

They have a tag for [flair](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/flair) that has this example question [se-flair: HTML combined Stack Exchange site flair](https://stackapps.com/questions/2119/se-flair-html-combined-stack-exchange-site-flair) as indicated by [brasofilo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/185667/brasofilo)

Comment: Well, se-flair is a pretty nifty web-app, maybe even rendering @Gerold's as a duplicate :)

Comment: @brasofilo That might be, at least we helped finding that for the OP ;)

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's lot to learn from that one. Good luck, OP, I mean GB!

Answer (score 0):

Thx @rene and @brasofilo.

It took and became longer than expected ([Pareto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle) hit me with no mercy: "the last 20 % take 80 % of the time" (:

[IGB Stack Flair](https://stackapps.com/questions/5004/igb-stack-flair-a-dynamic-flair-for-stackexchange-com-sites) - A dynamic flair for [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/) sites